# What have I done wrong with my Postfix config?

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, postfix

My mailserver has been sending emails fine and dandily to newsletter subscribers via the Mandrill app, but I have not been receiving emails on the domains I want, I only want mails to go to the user `jon` on the system.

My user mail file `var/mail/jon` is empty, I checked my `/var/log/mail.log` file and it is **massive**, with this error repeatedly:

`Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table;`

and

`Relay access denied;`

So obviously I have misconfigured my virtual domains in Postfix. These are my files:

[/etc/postfix/main.cf](https://physicle.com/view.php?id=RPVN0vfc)

[/etc/postfix/virtual](https://physicle.com/view.php?id=HDwgS3Ga)

Have I written the table in the `virtual` file wrong? I thought that `jon` would be the user that Postfix sends the mail too. Maybe that is not correct.

Do I need to change `jon` to some other value in the `virtual` file for mails to be delivered correctly? Like `jon@vps.domain.com`?

Apologies if this is rather broad, I do not have that much experience with Postfix. I have also since uncommented the TLS settings on my system before anyone mentions it.

(Ubuntu 14.04 system)

Answer (score 0):

If this is real user in your OS you should set it in "local recipient table". Here is described how to do it: https://serverfault.com/questions/179419/postfix-recipient-address-rejected-user-unknown-in-local-recipient-table

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Procmail was not installed.

Spotted an error about it missing in the mail log - Procmail is referenced in the `main.cf` file.

Have received one or two emails in the `jon` user mailbox now.

Comment: Cool :) So next time just be careful about the packages :)

Comment: Yeah I had reinstalled Ubuntu, uploaded my backed-up Postfix config file from the old installation and must have just forgotten to install Procmail.